# How to maximize a window that maximize button is disabled for it?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a program that Maximize button is disabled for it, but want to maximize it somehow.

I've tested <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, It doesn't work on it! I also tested <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, It doesn't work too.

Is there a way for doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your style! :P

If you're willing to go third party, the `WinMaximize` command from AutoHotKey doesn't care if the window can be maximized or not, it just does it.

```
!F3:: ;Maximize/Restore Window
WinGet MX, MinMax, A
If MX
WinRestore A
Else WinMaximize A
return
```

That script would toggle maximized on alt-F3 (because I assume you'll want to UNmaximize at some point :))

Comment: Well, where should I write it :) ?

Comment: @Mohammad; Oh, sorry! Install autohotkey, and place that in a text file with the extension `.ahk`, then run it.

Comment: Can we install it on Win 7 x64 ?

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, but it's not the way that I expected. I'm looking for a solution with the Windows ways.

Comment: @Moha; "The windows ways"? I don't believe there's any inbuilt method of doing this (And as you can probably see, many windows don't auto-resize the contents, there's no way around this)

Comment: Well, F. It worked with a MS Project modal, but the inner contents were still small. Nice trick anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If the window shows up in the Task Manager's Applications Tab, right-click on it there and, if the option isn't greyed-out, select Maximize--this will maximize even windows that don't "advertise" maximize support, i.e., that have neither the maximize button in the upper right corner nor in the system menu.  If, on the other hand, the window doesn't appear in the Applications Tab, e.g., is a sub-process window, then you're in the same boat I'm in, i.e., (still) trying to figure out how to do it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If the maximize button is disabled, it is not meant to be maximized. It probably does not even implement auto-resizing of the content so even if you *would* maximize the window, its content would not grow and you would just fill most of your screen with grey.

Comment: The program that I wanna maximize it, is a Flash Game, So it can be maximize easily!

Comment: @Mohammad if its not meant to be maximized and `Windows Key + Up` doesn't do the trick then you either have to go with @Phoshi's answer or open it in say IE or Chrome and maxamize that. If its a flash game you grabbed from a website you can load it in a customer html file and change the size that is displayed.

Comment: @MrStatic; It's a flash game that included in an other exe file and Maximize button is disabled on it!!! :(